# AngularStrap bs-select not updating ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using AngularStraps bs-select directive to add a multiple choice select button to one of my views. I'm trying to watch the values in this select box and run a search any time the values change.

My select button looks like this.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="subject_list" data-multiple="1"
  data-placeholder="All subjects" ng-options="subject.id as subject.name for subject in subjects" bs-select>
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

The problem is that $scope.subject_list never gets populated. The selection seems to work fine, and the ui all looks good, but ng-model never gets populated with anything.

In my controller, I initialize $scope.subject_list to an empty array, and then have a $watch function checking to see when it changes. Nothing ever gets fired. I even wrote a little function to print out the value of $scope.subject_list ever second, and it's always empty.

```
$scope.subject_list = [];
$scope.$watch('subject_list', $scope.update_search);
$scope.update_search = function(){
  console.log($scope.subject_list);
};
```

Any thoughts as to what's going on? I had this working at one point, so I'm either doing something silly, or a recent update broke things.

## Update

This seems to be a scope inheritance issue. I've got all kinds of scopes going on, which could be part of the problem. However, I was able to get this working by doing everything on the rootScope. So...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="$root.subject_list" data-multiple="1"
  data-placeholder="All subjects" ng-options="subject.id as subject.name for subject in subjects" bs-select>
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

and

```
$rootScope.subject_list = [];
$rootScope.$watch('subject_list', function(){
    console.log('change');
});
```

I'm sure this isn't the best way to do this, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my scopes.

Comment: Can you replicate it in a plunkr please? It could be something else in your code as that looks the same as the example on AngularStrap. If it's an isolation issue you could try putting `subject_list` inside an object and referencing it that way.

Comment: I'm noticing that I'm having the same issue with other select modules, like this one [http://nya.io/nya-bootstrap-select/](http://nya.io/nya-bootstrap-select/). Seems like no matter what, the ng-model isn't getting set. I tried setting up a plunkr, but when I tried loading angular strap, it bombed out. I can try with this other module.

Comment: Try create it from the Live Demo plunkr off of angular-strap here: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/tooltips#selects (click the "plunker" link next to "Live Demo"). Then you know that it's got the correct files loaded and should work. Personally I'd avoid using modules like the one you linked as it's just a clever wrapper for the jquery plugin which means you have a lot of code bloat.

Comment: Ok, I've narrowed it down to some type of scope inheritance issue. If I put everything in the top level scope, it all works fine. However, when I'm a couple levels down, something's up. The select actually seems to be working fine. When I put {{subject_list}} in the view itself, it gets updated fine. But in the controller it never changes.

Comment: You might be able to get around it via `{{$parent.subject_list}}`, $parent references the the parent of the current scope. If you can post up the structure with directives from the `ng-controller` tag to the `bs-select` tag there might be something there (unless of course it's in a custom directive). If it's a custom directive then if possible remove the `scope: ...` option which will stop it from creating a child scope.

Comment: Looks like just using {{$parent.subject_list}} works fine. I also think I figured out where the issue is happening. I'll post it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here came down to a scoping issue. I was using ui.router and the $stateProvider with lots of nested states and views.

I had one abstract state, which I set the controller in for all sub states.

```
.state('profiles.search',{
    url: '/search',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view/>',
    controller: 'SearchCtrl'
  })

  .state('profiles.search.classrooms', {
    url: '/classrooms',
    templateUrl: 'views/classrooms/search.html',
    data: {
      update_classrooms: true
    }
  })
```

What I didn't realize is, is that when the templateUrl for the 'profiles.search.classroom' state is rendered, it gets its own scope, that is inherited from the 'profiles.search' scope, where all my scope variables live in SearchCtrl.

So, I can initialize data from SearchCtrl, but it doesn't bind back from the view, because it is its own scope.

Moral of the story, make sure you know which scope you're working in.

Comment: If the scope for the `profiles.search.classrooms` state inherits from the parent state scope, what's the problem? You should be able to access properties in the scope chain.

Comment: @AlejandroIglesias, it's just a matter of which level of the scope you're working in. In the view for profiles.search.classrooms, I can access the scope from profiles.search, however, when I change something in the view for profiles.search.classrooms, it's one scope level lower than profiles.search, where the controller lives. Thus, the data does not bind back. At least that's what I've seen.

Comment: well, you should define your model in the parent controller and then change it however you want in the child controller. You will be able to change inherited properties, not properties defined locally in the child.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. There's only 1 controller involved here. It's in the parent scope. The child scope has it's own view, but uses the parent controller. The data isn't binding back from the child view to the parent controller. That's the issue I'm having. Ultimately I had to use {{$parent.subject_list}} to bind to the correct subject_list. Maybe that's not expected behavior?

Comment: sorry, you're right, there's no "child" controller involved in here. Yes, your approach using `$parent` is correct "for now". I say that because the recommended approach is changing to "named scopes" (ie, `ng-controller="SearchCtrl as search"` and using it as `{{search.subject_list}}`).
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too on one of the `bs-select`s on page, but not the other. Turned out that if you assigned the `ng-model` to a property on an object on your scope it works fine. i.e:

```
ng-model="props.selecteditem"
```

when

```
$scope.props = {
    selecteditem: ''
}
```

did the trick.

Comment: angularstrap `bs-select` is really, really counter intuitive on this. I believe it is the third time I have spent an hour solving this, wondering why there was no binding, only to face that `bs-select` only will bind to a nested value and only if it is present.  I really dislike frameworks that overcomplicate things or try to do things "better". It is almost unbelieveable that a simple freaking `<select>` can be implemented so weird that you actually need a manual to use it. In angular!!