# angular-strap: input tag in modal and aside

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I use an input tag in angular-strap modal:

```
<div class="modal-body" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="url" class="w-full" >
</div>
```

Then I type some words in it and close the modal with `hide()`.
But next time I open the modal, I find that what I typed last time has gone.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't have an ng-model attached to that input, and if you pass in a controller it re-initializes everytime you open the modal. I wouldn't expect it to maintain the value of the last time you opened the modal

Comment: I have tried what you say, I use a ng-model on the input, and I $scope.kmlUrl ="xx"; And i init modal by ` kmlModal = $modal({
                              scope: $scope, 
                             
                              template: 'tpl/kmlSelectModal.html',
                              show: true
                            });` but the kmlUrl did not work with the ng-modal kmlUrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a working plunkr here: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VOdA5QGnvVdPcF9yW8xJ).  Take note of making kmlUrl an object key instead of a straight var: [AngularStrap bs-select not updating ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129947/angularstrap-bs-select-not-updating-ng-model)

The modal and page are now in sync with each other. The modal loads whatever is in $scope.model.kmlUrl and the page updates whenever you change it in the modal.

```
<div ng-controller="TestModal">
  <button type="button" ng-click="openTestModal()">
    Open Modal
  </button>
  <div ng-cloak="">
    {{ model.kmlUrl }}
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="test-modal.html">
  <input type="text" placeholder="url" ng-model="model.kmlUrl">
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" ng-click="closeTestModal()">Close</button>
  </div>
</script>

(function(){
  angular.module('test', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);

  angular.module('test').controller('TestModal', function($scope, $modal){
    var modal = $modal({
      scope: $scope,
      title: 'Test Modal',
      contentTemplate: 'test-modal.html',
      show: false
     });

    $scope.model = {
      kmlUrl: 'https://www.amazon.com'
    };

    $scope.openTestModal = function(){
     modal.show();
    };

    $scope.closeTestModal = function(){
      modal.hide();
    };

  });
})();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but i use the angular-strap project not ui-bootstrap

Comment: Updated with code from http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals, is this the correct library?